# Read information from one file and update the content of the other file

Tags: java

How the code should work: Read a student file that contain firstName, lastName, studentNo, DOB. Read another file, scores of the student, which contain firstAssignment, project, finalExam and add the scores to the student file so that when you print the student file it will display out, firstName, lastName, studentNo, DOB, firstAssignment, project, finalExam.

Current code: My code is able to display out firstName, lastName, studentNo, DOB, firstAssignment, project, finalExam but what I did was that I use 2 files instead of one. So I have one student arraylist and scores arraylist.

Current code
Read and store the scores of the student

```
public static void optionTwo(ArrayList<Unit> scores, ArrayList<Student> students, Scanner      scan){

    System.out.print("Please enter a file for Student Score:");
    String infileName = scan.next();
    Scanner reader = null;

        try {
            int index = 0;
            reader = new Scanner(new File(infileName));
            while (reader.hasNext()){
                String oneLine = reader.nextLine();
                String[] parts = oneLine.split(" ");

                int levelOfUnit = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                int firstAssignment = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                int secondAssignmentOrProject = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
                int weeklyPracticalWork = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
                int finalExam = Integer.parseInt(parts[5]);


                if (students.get(index) instanceof Student_Common){
                    scores.add(index, new Unit_Common(parts[0], levelOfUnit, firstAssignment, secondAssignmentOrProject,
                            weeklyPracticalWork, finalExam));
                }

                if (students.get(index) instanceof Student_Major){
                    scores.add(index, new Unit_Major(parts[0], levelOfUnit, firstAssignment, secondAssignmentOrProject,
                            weeklyPracticalWork, finalExam));
                }

                index++;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
}
```

Print out the information

```
public static void optionFour(ArrayList<Student> students, ArrayList<Unit> scores){
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
    System.out.print(students.get(i) + " ");

            try {
                System.out.println(scores.get(i));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
                System.out.println();
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Weird, there shouldn't be a backslash in the code. sorry for not noticing before posting the question.

Comment: What in the 'Student Scores' file actually relates to the student contained within the 'Students' file. There needs to be a common element which ties the two entities together. Normally this would be something like a **Student ID**. This then means that each object stored within the 'Student Scores' file contains a 'Student ID' which actually relates to a specific student within the 'Students' file, a one to many relationship whereas for each student in the 'Students' file there are many scores (for different assignments) within the 'Student Scores' file. How do you who owns the scores?

Comment: I should think that this is where **Student** and **StudentScores** classes would come in handy.

Comment: Oh okay I think I understand, so what you are saying is that to create that link for Student file and Scores file, I just need to add the studentID attribute to the scores file? How will the java code format be like in order to establish the relationship between Student file and Score file using studentID as like a primary key?

Comment: That is correct, you would want to add a StudentID attribute (instance member) to the **StudentScores** file. This way when you want assignment scores for a specific Student that holds a unique Student ID, you just need to search through the StudentScores file for that ID and retrieve the assignment(s) data (scores, etc) you specifically want. Create a **Student** class and also create a **StudentScores** class so to work with the data much easier and faster. You will also find that file access will be greatly reduced. If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I didn't expect there is a need to use SQL knowledge in Java Programming. If that is okay with you can you show me an example, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Because of the overall size of the demo, it is not feasible to place in several posts here so, you can [get it from here](https://controlc.com/7ae2f966).